# How to make Python Web Server public?

Tags: python, timestamp, ip, webserver, public

I had the idea to synchronise the equal scripts from a python program
that Im running on different computers in parallel, by creating a
global timestamp based of the script that startet first.

So for a better explanation, it should work like this:

The Script runs on PC 1 and creates a timestamp.
Everything the script has to do after that will only be executed once
the time in the timestamp + 5 minutes is reached.

For the script on PC 2 or more, basically the same is happening but without
creating a new timestamp, since the starting time wouldnt be the
same anymore then.

Now I already build a Python webserver that creates the timestamp and I am
also able to retrieve the time for my script. But I have to make sure that I
can reach the webserver without beeing in my own network and
using "localhost:..." as an adress. So now I wonder how I can make the webserver
public in the most easy way possible. The other option would be an
already public site, that can create custom timestamps on the basis of my configuration, so that I only create 1 timestamp for the first visitor on the site.

Do you by chance know any of these sites or can tell me how I can make my HTML web server public?

Thanks

Comment: For simple python apps, you may be well served with Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python

Answer (score 3):

You could check out a few hosting options. With a little bit of configuration work, you can probably get your software to run on [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python) or [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/), which would make it available on e.g. `https://mytimestampserver.herokuapp.com` or `https://mytimestampserver.pythonanywhere.com`. Both services offer a relatively generous free tier.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a simple Flask that's listening on port `5555` on PC1:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5555)
```

That page is accessible from your computer at localhost:5555.
If PC1 is in a LAN, same page is accessible from the same subnet at `<PC1-ip-address>:5555`.

If PC1 has a public IP address, then the site can be accessed from the Internet at `<PC1-public-ip-address>:5555`.

If PC1 is behind a router, unless your Internet Service Provider isn't blocking or filtering this, you should be able to create a forwarding rule from the `router-public-IP-address:<some-port>` to `PC1-ip-address>:5555` and access the site from the internet at `router-public-IP-address:<some-port>`.

Furthermore, you can buy a domain and have the domain name address resolved to the public IP that you own and use on your router.

If you cannot reserve the public IP address at your Internet Service Provider, then you can use Dynamic DNS and have it automatically updated once your router detects that its public IP address has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a proxy server on the same network with the pc you have the script running on and connect to it from the other pcs

Answer (score 1):

You could use an amazon service like elastickbeanstalk its free to some extent and will make your server public